# Why 'nodemailer' does not send any message?

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

Here is the code:

```
var nodemailder = require('nodemailer');
var from = nodemailder.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    auth:{
        user: 'user***@gmail.com',
        pass: 'pass***'
    }
});
var options = {
     from: 'user***@gmail.com',
     to: 'user***@gmail.com',
     subject: 'sometext',
     text: 'messageContext',
};
from.sendMail(options, function (error, info) {
     if (error) {
            console.log(error);
     } else {
            console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
     }
});
```

If I use Windows - it works, when I tried to start on Ubuntu (16) - I dont get any error message etc., but the mail was not received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is the case, I believe SMTP service is unable to make connection to connection on port 25.

Running server will look like:

```
$ telnet localhost 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 xxxx.de ESMTP Postfix
QUIT
221 2.0.0 Bye
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

If there is no server listening on this port, it will like this:

```
$ telnet localhost 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

This means your services might not be running or enabled. You need to first enable/run this service on port 25.

Also,  according to the nodemail documentation you can use the sendmail binary as well:

```
'sendmail' alternative

Alternatively if you don't want to use SMTP but the sendmail
```

command then set property sendmail to true (or as the path to sendmail if the command is not in default path).

```
nodemailer.sendmail = true;

or

nodemailer.sendmail = '/path/to/sendmail';

If sendmail is set, then SMTP options are discarded.
```

for reference, https://nodemailer.com/transports/sendmail/